# Suppress error in lldb 'type category delete' command

Tags: python, lldb

#### Summary

I would like to suppress error messages in the lldb

```
type category delete Name
```

command, which occur if the specified category does not exist.

#### Background and details

I'm using type summaries to get customized descriptions for various types in a larger project.
Here is a minimal example, just to demonstrate the problem:

```py
import lldb
import shlex
import optparse

def __lldb_init_module (debugger, dict):
    debugger.HandleCommand('type category delete MyApp')
    debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add --python-script \'return "BOO"\' --category MyApp BooType')
    debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add --python-script \'return "WHOA"\' --category MyApp WhoaType')
    debugger.HandleCommand('type category enable MyApp')
```

The type summaries are put into a dedicated category, so that they can be
enabled and disabled easily. The first thing the script does is to delete
all my custom type summaries, to that I can make changes in the Python code
and reload it from the running debug session with

```
(lldb) command script import /path/to/test.py
```

The only problem is that this will print an error message when the script is
loaded the first time:

```
(lldb) command script import /path/to/test.py
error: cannot delete one or more categories
```

Is there a way to suppress this error message, or to call the `type category delete`
command only if the category already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches you could take here.

The simplest is to still add your categories & formatters through command line commands, and just suppress the error output:

SBDebugger.HandleCommand is not the only way to run commands in the SB API.  There is also SBCommandInterpreter.HandleCommand.  The SBDebugger version is meant for convenience (e.g. when in the interactive script interpreter), but as you see gives you no control over the result.

There's another variant provided by the SBInterpreter that allows you to capture the command result, which is useful both because it allows you to operate programmatically on the result, but is also handy if you just want to suppress the output.  So, instead of what you have, do:

```
interp = debugger.GetCommandInterpreter()
result = lldb.SBCommandReturnObject()
interp.HandleCommand('type category delete MyApp', result)
```

This call won't echo the result of the command to the debugger output, it's up to you do do that if you want.  You can check if the command succeeded with `result.Succeeded()` and so forth.

But the SB API's also provide direct access to the type categories and the formatters, summaries, and synthetic child providers they contain.  So for instance you can do:

```
my_app_category = debugger.GetCategory("MyApp")
if not my_app_category:
    debugger.CreateCategory("MyApp")
```

You can also use the SBTypeCategory API's to access the formatters in that category programmatically if you want to go that way:

https://lldb.llvm.org/python_api/lldb.SBTypeCategory.html

Comment: Btw, what I am still looking for is a good *tutorial* on lldb scripting, something that goes beyond the basics covered in https://lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html.

Comment: If you haven't looked at https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html, that might get you a little further.  And there are a bunch of useful examples in https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/lldb/examples/python that you can learn from.  You might also check out Derek Selander's 'Advanced Apple Debugging and Reverse Engineering'.  And be sure to browse the Python API docs page for interesting classes & methods.